# Undock Keyboard Programmatically?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I suppose that it is not possible for us to programmatically undock the virtual keyboard.  If possible, of course, I would like to know how.  I also suppose that it is not possible for us to turn the **Split Keyboard** switch (General > Keyboard) on programmatically.

Anyway, my situation is the following.  I have a tableview control at the top and a textview control right below it with a toolbar control at the bottom.  The textview control is editable.  So if a user touches it, the virtual keyboard will open, covering the bottom toolbar control.  And this keyboard will cover the buttons on the toolbar control.  What can I do so that a user can have access to these buttons?  I do have a notification ready with **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification** and **UIKeyboardWillHideNotification** so that I can tell when a user touches the textview control.  Place the toolbar control somewhere else other than at the very bottom?  I hope I don't have to do that.  Maybe, move the entire view way up while the keyboard is up?  I think I can do that.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I think this is probably not good UI. Your keyboard should just cover the tab bar while you're in editing mode and then make it easy to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just decided to move the entire frame upwards when the virtual keyboard is open.  It doesn't look bad.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
// NSLog(@"It's appeared.");

keyboardup = true;
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y-300,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

}

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
// NSLog(@"It's gone");

keyboardup = false;
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y+300,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

}

```
- (void)keyboardCallingNotifications {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```